# All class members and autowired fields of a @Service class that also contains a @Transactional method are null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@Service
Class ServiceA{

private final logger =...;

@Autowired
private UtilA utilA;

@Transactional
public Object methodA(){
...}
}
```

When I run a test that calls methodA, I get an NPE because UtilA and the logger are null and they were not initialised.

However, if I move the @transactional to the unit test, everything is fine. But, I cannot do that in reality. What could I be doing wrong ?

Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: Could you please correct your code examples and also include your current Unit Test code? It's a bit hard to figure out what's going on right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is difficult to answer your question based on the info you have described. Probably, code snippets of your tests would help.

What is more important - when you do unit testing, you shouldn't use Spring. Unit tests should cover your code, not Spring's ability to create a transaction for you. You have to use mocks to avoid difficulties with null dependencies.

In your case, if you are using Spring even for unit testing, probably, the problem is in the way you autowire deps. When you do it by field, your service can be instantiated by Spring without autowiring dependency in advance. However, when you add @Transactional in the test, I believe Spring processes your test longer and by that time, dependency is autowired. Try to use autowiring via a constructor. It is better in 2 ways:

1. It will force Spring to manage dependency first - no chance to fail with NPE when you are in the method. Your class should throw exceptions when it can't find all required dependencies.
2. Class will have a more transparent interface.